# Why are __block variables not retained (In non-ARC environments)?

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, objective-c-blocks

I was reading through the documentation on [__block variables](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxVariables.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007502-CH6-SW6), and thinking about the cases where I use __block.  To me, it seems like I need it in two cases:

- To mark a variable as read-write when used within a block
- To avoid retain cycles when referencing self within a block

On the surface it doesn't seem like these two things are related.  I consider the fact that __block variables not being retained as more of a trick I need to remember for the specific use case of avoiding retain cycles.

I'm wondering, is there a more important, architectural reason why they must not be retained?  I would think some other keyword to indicate this might be more clear, as to not mix up the two features listed above.

update -

I should mention this is code that does not use ARC.  I now see that __block variables are in fact retained in ARC.

Comment: You only use `__block` for the first. You use `__weak`, not `__block`, to avoid retain cycles.

Comment: Also, where did you get the idea that __block variables are not retained? ARC will retain them for you automatically, just like regular variables.

Comment: Before ARC, __block variables were indeed not retained as a mechanism to avoid retain cycles. That changed with ARC and is documented in the Transitioning to ARC Release Notes.

Comment: @MartinR Right! I just came across this document. I was indeed referring to code not using ARC.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`__block` variables are not retained if you use Manual Reference Counting. The reason can be found here: http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2009-08-14-practical-blocks.html:

> A simple workaround to this lies in the fact that `__block` variables
>   are not retained. This is because such variables are mutable, and
>   automatic memory management of them would require each mutation to
>   generate memory management code behind the scenes. This was seen as
>   too intrusive and difficult to get right, especially since the same
>   block may be executing from multiple threads simultaneously.

and also here: http://lists.apple.com/archives/objc-language/2009/Dec/msg00100.html

> There is no way to properly and efficiently manage the retain counts
>   upon re-assignment of the value within the variable.

(I could not find an "official" reference in the Apple documentation.)

As documented in the ["Transitioning to ARC Release Notes"](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html), this behavior changed with ARC:

> In manual reference counting mode, `__block id x;` has the effect of not
>   retaining `x`. In ARC mode, `__block id x;` defaults to retaining x (just
>   like all other values). To get the manual reference counting mode
>   behavior under ARC, you could use `__unsafe_unretained __block id x;`.
>   As the name __unsafe_unretained implies, however, having a
>   non-retained variable is dangerous (because it can dangle) and is
>   therefore discouraged. Two better options are to either use `__weak` (if
>   you don’t need to support iOS 4 or OS X v10.6), or set the `__block`
>   value to `nil` to break the retain cycle.

Comment: @darren: After reading those references again it seems to me that avoiding retain cycles is more a side-effect than a design goal of __block variables.